# GZip for PHP on IIS

Tags: php, iis, gzip

If GZip is enabled in IIS is it only going to improve performance for ASP pages or can it be setup to compress PHP pages as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP also has built in support for gzip compression. You can initialize it by calling

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

or by activating the zlib.output_compression directive in php.ini.

Comment: It's independent of webserver. All the processing is done "before" the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gzip just compresses the content being served to the browser i.e. html and images.